# Play: validate JSON with a field with possible multiple types

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I use Scala case classes and Play "format" to validate JSON messages. For example:

```
case class Person(name: String)
implicit val formatPerson = Json.format[Person]
```

The following JSON:

```
{
    "name": "Alice"
}
```

would be validated through the method

```
Json.validate[Person](json)
```

Now I would like to validate a JSON message with a field "x" that could be a String or a Integer.
For example the two following messages would be both validated with the same method:

```
{
    "x": "hello"
}  


{
    "x": 8
}
```

I tried with the following trick but it does not work:

```
case class Foo(x: Either[String,Int])
implicit val formatFoo = Json.format[Foo]
```

When I try to define the format for Foo class, the compiler says: "No apply function found matching unapply parameters". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to define a custom `Format[Foo]`.  This should work for Play 2.4

```
implicit val formatFoo = new Format[Foo]{
  override def writes(o: Foo): JsValue = o.x match {
    case Left(str) => Json.obj("x" -> str)
    case Right(n) => Json.obj("x" -> n)
  }
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Foo] = json \ "x" match {
    case JsDefined(JsString(str)) => JsSuccess(Foo(Left(str)))
    case JsDefined(JsNumber(n)) if n.isValidInt => JsSuccess(Foo(Right(n.toInt)))
    case _ => JsError("error")
  }
}
```